# How to get records from a table based on the quantity of a value in an other table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I have table A (cities)

id,   city,   country

And table B (trips)

id,   trip,   city,   active

I want to select all cities with MySQL but order them on how many times they show up in table B when active is 1.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then left join `B` on `A` and include active=1 condition in the join clause and group by city.

```
select a.city, count(b.city) as cnt
from a
left join b on a.id=b.city and b.active=1
group by a.id, a.city
order by count(b.city) desc
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try both queries and compare performance

```
select a.city, count(*) as cnt
from cities as a
left join
trips as b
on (a.id = b.city and b.active=1)
group by a.city
order by 2 desc
```

or

```
select
    a.city,
    (select count(*) from trips as b where a.id = b.city and b.active=1) as cnt
from cities as a
order by 2 desc
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, but I want all to get all the cities, but show cities without active trips at the bottom. With this query I only get the cities with active trips.

Comment: Yeah that's the whole point of b.active = 1.  They're specifically pulling trips that are labelled as active.  That's because that's what you asked for, "...show up in table B when active is 1."

Comment: @Benidorm for first query I've updated to use left join, this will show all cities, second query shows all cities by default

Comment: @Benidorm then take a look at my solution because it addresses this issue by using count(b.city) for counting, not count(*).